# Angular IDE does not launch after installing

Tags: angular, ide, angular-ide

To install angular IDE I followed [the instructions](https://www.genuitec.com/products/angular-ide/download/). Also my terminal log provided:

```
~npm install -g angular-ide
/usr/local/bin/ngide -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-ide/bin/ngide

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-ide/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-ide/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> angular-ide@0.9.38 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-ide
> node ./scripts/post.js

+ angular-ide@0.9.38
added 336 packages in 16.807s
```

next command also terminated successfully:

```
ngide install ~/Development/angular-ide
Installing Angular IDE in: /Users/sergii_vlasiuk/Development/angular-ide
Downloading...[====================] 100%
Extracting....[====================] 100%
The Angular IDE has been installed.
```

check `ngide` version:

```
~ngide --version
0.9.38
```

other details:

```
npm -v
5.6.0

node -v
v8.2.1
```

Trying to start `ngide` in similar way as it described in tutorial:

```
ngide open ./README.md 

Opening the Angular IDE for: /Users/.../README.md
Starting Angular IDE...
The Angular IDE did not start correctly.

macOS Sierra
```

Comment: Try executing this command with root previliges

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma Result is the same. I would be confused if it start because of installation processed with usual privileges.

Comment: I have same problem with the same version of tools. macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Comment: I have the same issue; has anyone found a solution?